# How to change glibc version directory for perl?

Tags: perl, gcc, glibc

Currently, I'm using Ubuntu, and I have a myplatform_sysroot directory used for Qt cross-platform build purposes.

And when configuring qt to build I face an issue regarding perl as below:

*perl: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by perl)*

I also tried to cd to myplatform_sysroot/usr/bin and run *./perl --version*, then I got the same error.

After checking by running "ldd --version" in my ubuntu, I see the current GLIBC versio is **2.27**. And running "./myplatform_sysroot/usr/bin/ldd --version" the GLIBC version in the myplatform_sysroot is **2.28**. I guess that perl in myplatform_sysroot link to the GLIBC in my Ubuntu lead to the above error.

So I'd like to ask if there are any ways to specify the GLIBC version to myplatform_sysroot, not host Ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: huh? How did you build that `perl`? Did you build it on a different system and copied the files over?

Comment: @ikegami, yes, perl is stored in sysroot/usr/bin, and it was built on a different system.

Comment: I install patchelf utility and run: patchelf --set-interpreter myplatfrom_sysroot/lib/ld-linux.so.2 --set-rpath myplatform_sysroot/lib/ myplatform_sysroot/usr/bin/perl. Then I didn't get the issue `GLIBC_2.28' not found any more. But I get another error: "Cwd.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xde00080, needed 0x
ce00080)"

Comment: Update: I export PERL5LIB=all path to myplatform_sysroot/lib/perl, then the issue is passed. eg:  export PERL5LIB=myplatform_sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/:myplatform_sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base:myplatform_sysroot/etc/perl:myplatform_sysroot/usr/share/perl

Comment: Use relocateble lib dirs when you build perl. Not sure what the option is named. Look at INTSTALL. This will avoid the need to set PERL5LIB